# trim song using ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my site built on Ruby on Rails, I need to provide functionality to trim songs (say first 20 sec). Does anybody know any relevant API to manipulate songs (like 'rmagick' for images)?

Comment: You could try this one: https://github.com/warhammerkid/ruby-audio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try https://github.com/fugalh/ruby-audio. It looks a little out of date, but there's probably a fork with updates.

Another solution might be to limit how much the song plays via javascript.
And yet another option might be just to make the snippets yourself.

Comment: You assume that he write webapp? Why?

Comment: He said he has a site built on ruby on rails.

Comment: Awww... Yeah. I haven't seen :)